# "main" has not been registered - Expo Project issue with iOS

Tags: react-native-ios

I am using an expo managed react-native project and it seems to be running fine on android but not iOS. For iOs i get the following error message :

"'main' has not been registered. This can happen if: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

- A module failed to load due to an error and 'AppRegistry.registerComponent' wasn't called."

I have tried updating my index.js using AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App) from similar posts but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**index.js**

```
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import App from "./App";

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () 
=> App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in the Expo client or in 
a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);
```

**App.js**

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { ScreenStack } from "react-native-screens";
import Login from "./Login";
import Join from "./Join";
import Home from "./Home";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import BorrowMap from "./BorrowMap";
import SpotRequest from "./SpotRequest";
// import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{ title: "Welcome" }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{ title: "Login" }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Join"
          component={Join}
          options={{ title: "Register" }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Dashboard"
          component={Dashboard}
          options={{ title: "Dashboard" }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Spot Request"
          component={SpotRequest}
          options={{ title: "Spot Request Details" }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Finding Buddy"
          component={BorrowMap}
          options={{ title: "Finding Buddy" }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default App;
```

**Folder Structure**

[image]